# How do you send a query to a neo4j server from Elasticsearch devtools?

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, neo4j, data-visualization, neo4j-apoc

I have a neo instance and a Elasticsearch instance running on a docker compose container.
I would like to eventually create visualization using Elasticsearch using Neo4j data but first I need to find a way to get the two to talk. I have the APOC plugin also if that is relevant. What is the syntax for talking to neo from Devtools in Elastic? Here is what I have so far

Works on Neo4j:

```
call apoc.bolt.load("bolt://neo4j:fall2021@localhost:7687","match(n) RETURN n LIMIT 5")
```

Does not work on Elastic:

```
GET apoc.bolt.load("bolt://neo4j:fall2021@localhost:7687")
```

Comment: There is no way to do that from Elastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo the above comments, you cannot do this.

Kibana will only ever talk to the Elasticsearch instance it has been configured to talk to.

Comment: So what is the relationship between neo and elastic? I have seen some integration efforts online but?

Comment: no idea, this is outside the scope of the Elasticsearch that we build sorry, so I have no knowledge of it